# How do I configure Azure Cache to use my custom IDataCacheObjectSerializer class?

Tags: azure

How do I configure Azure Cache in web roles to use my custom IDataCacheObjectSerializer class?  In case you are wondering why I want to use a custom serializer: I want to use the compact text based style JSON(.net) serialization combined with compression. In my .config files I can enable compression:

```
<dataCacheClient name="default" isCompressionEnabled="true"/>
```

But how / where do I tell Azure Cache (preview) to use my custom IDataCacheObjectSerializer class that uses JSON serialization?

Comment: Check if this thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756480/appfabric-caching-can-i-specify-serialization-style-used-for-all-objects.

Answer (score 3):

Jagan Peri has a [relevant blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jagan_peri/archive/2012/08/23/custom-serializer.aspx).

From the post:

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <tracing sinkType="DiagnosticSink" traceLevel="Verbose" />

    <!-- This is the default config which is used for all Named Caches
    This can be overriden by specifying other dataCacheClient sections with name being the NamedCache name -->

    <dataCacheClient name="default" useLegacyProtocol="false">
        <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="WorkerRole1" />
        <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
        <serializationProperties serializer="CustomSerializer" customSerializerType="Your.Fully.Qualified.Path.To.IDataCacheObjectSerializer,WorkerRole1" />
    </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

Comment: wow great read, thats exactly what I was looking for.  I added the config stuff since that should answer the question completely